# Jenkins: ignore exit status 255

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I use a Jenkins Pipeline for the deployment of a PHP Application. 
In this pipeline I run the following php command on a remote server:

```
php /var/www/path/public/index.php &> /dev/null
```

I use **&> /dev/null** to hide the ouput because it returns errors.
The issue is that the pipeline fails because of that and returns following error:

```
org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.BadExitStatusException: Command returned exit status 255: php /var/www/path/public/index.php &> /dev/null
```

Is there a way to ignore the status code 255 an prevent stopping the deployment ?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
php /var/www/path/public/index.php &> /dev/null || true
```

This effectively hides the outcome from php command and gives always 0 as return value.